# Constant folding vs. Constant propogation

Tags: compilers, program-optimization

What is the difference between constant folding and constant propogation? They both seem to do the same thing, instead of saving constants into stack or evaluating a full arithmetic expression, they simply replace it with the result which can be obtained at compile time. What is the difference between two?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on these two websites: http://www.compileroptimizations.com/category/constant_folding.htm and 
http://www.compileroptimizations.com/category/constant_propagation.htm

The difference is that constant propogation is not saving a variable to the stack, because we know its a constant (like `x = 10;`) and can simply plug it in everywhere (say if you had an expression `y = x + x + x` => `y = 10 + 10 + 10`) it is used in machine code. Whereas, constant folding is simply evaluating expressions that use constants and substituting the result into the machine code (like `y = 10 + 10 + 10;` => `y = 30;`)

Comment: Other than there's no reason stacks and machine code need to be involved (you can do these as source-to-source translations for example), yes, this is the distinction. Constant propagation just replaces a bound variable with the constant expression it's bound to, while constant folding evaluates a (side-effect free) expression where all inputs are compile-time constants.

Comment: @DerekElkins yeah, the no side effects part is an importnat note

Answer (score 0):

Constant propagation is entirely different.

What it does is gather information about the values of variables and propagates it to different locations in a program. For example, if you assign x = 5, then y = x, then z = y * 3, then a = x + y + z, and there are no assignments interfering with this, then constant propagation tells as that y = 5, z = 5 * 3 (which turns into z = 15 after constant folding), and a = 25.

Instead of just constant values, other values can be propagated. For example, after x = 5, y = x, z = y * 3, if (condition) z += y, we know that 15 <= z <= 20. Knowledge about ranges can remove overflow checks, can allow using faster instructions that can handle only smaller numbers, can remove comparisons like if (x <= 25) which will be true, can give hints whether loop unrolling should be done or should not be done etc.

Answer (score -1):

In constant folding you only submit the result.
For example, in constant folding you turn `y=3+4` into `y=7`.

In contrast, in constant propagation, the constant replaces a variable.
For example, given

```
int x=6;
for(i=0;i<x;i++)
```

you simple replace the value of `x` by the constant:

```
for(i=0;i<6;i++)
```